# lldb throwing error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSMakeRange'

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb, foundation, nsrange

If I pause an app's execution and try this command in the debugger: `po NSMakeRange(0, 1)` I receive the error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSMakeRange'
>   error: 1 errors parsing expression

I tried using `expr @import Foundation` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the next create `NSRange` variable:

```
e NSRange $range = {.location = 2, .length = 1}
po range
```

But as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835886/how-to-create-and-use-temp-nsrange-in-lldb) iOS, "NSRange is just a forward declaration and I do not know the real symbol for the implementation". That is why you may have issues with using this `range` variable in the debugger.

Comment: Use `po $range` to get the variable.